# How can I create custom predefined constant?

Tags: php, constants

I need to define custom constant, that would be visible in all my php files. Maybe I can use php.ini or there is a module that would allow me to do this? I would rather avoid using auto_prepend_file.

I was asking google a lot, but didn't find the answer, I am wondering if it possible at all.

I am using private server so I have access to root user and all files.

edit: added information about that I don't want to use auto_prepend_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `auto_prepend_file` in Your `.htaccess`/`php.ini` and define constants/variables in it

[Manual Page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I don't want to use this particular solution. I was thinking rather of something closer to real predefined constant. If there is no other way, I will use auto_prepend_file but I'd rather avoid this.